# Share my site photos on Instagram through PHP API

Tags: php, api, share, instagram

I am working on E-Commerce site which is share my product images to Facebook and Twitter but my client wants to share products images on Instagram as well. This is possible through PHP API.

Thanks,

Comment: So have you researched the various Instagram APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Instagram API does not allow you to post pictures. You are still required to post images via the Instagram application.

Here is the Instagram API documentation. There is no endpoint for creating media. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/